# return each time the same result even by changing the value

Tags: javascript

hope you are doing well :)
I am doing an exercise where I have to convert the input value from CM to INCH and from INCH to CM.
when I enter a value for the first time, it works, but when I want to modify the value, it does not want to work.
i get each time the same result even by changing the value.
thanks a lot

```
<!-- cm to inch -->
<input type="text" placeholder="please insert a number " id="inputNumber" />
<button type="button" onclick="cmToInch()">convert to cm</button>
<button type="button" onclick="inchToCm()">convert to inch</button>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
  const result = document.getElementById("result");
  const inputNumber = document.getElementById("inputNumber");
  const numValue = inputNumber.value;

  const cmToInch = () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerText = +numValue * 2.54;
    result.appendChild(div);
  };

  const inchToCm = () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerText = +numValue / 2.54;
    result.appendChild(div);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: That's because you are only reading the value of the input field one time. `inputNumber.value` - `value` is not an object (which would be passed by reference), but a scalar value. You need to do this _inside_ of your functions.

Comment: Move the 3 const definitions into your functions.